# Why does CodeIgniter return my SQL query as an array, with an object inside?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have constructed a **model** within codeigniter named *'Profile_model'* which contains the following sql queries, and is supposed to return the **user_name** of the user with a given **id** (*'userpdata'* is the table which contains this info) :

```
public function get_username($id)
{
  $query = $this->db->select('user_name')
                    ->where('id', $id)
                    ->get('userpdata');
  return $query->result();
}
```

I have passed in the $id of the current user from the controller like so (model is referred to as *'profile'*):

```
$userId = strval($this->ion_auth->get_user_id());
$data = array(
    'username' => $this->profile->get_username($userId)
    );

$this->load->view('user/profile', $data);
```

**user/profile** view:

```
<?php 
  print_r($username);
?>
```

This returns the string:

*Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_name] => hish ) )*

Which appears to be an array containing an object. How can I retrieve just the *user_name* **'hish'**?

Comment: generally search results are always an array of arrays or an array of objects. CI's undoubtedly using its db library of choice's "fetchObject()" function when retrieving results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$query->result();` to `$query->row();` so that you don't get an array. The `result()` method returns an array of rows, each of which is an object. The `row()` method returns the first object of the result set.

```
public function get_username($id)
{
  $query = $this->db->select('user_name')
                    ->where('id', $id)
                    ->get('userpdata');
  return $query->row();
}
```

You will end up with the object that contains the property `user_name`. You could either get the value of it in the controller.

```
$user = $this->profile->get_username($userId);
$data = array(
    'username' => $user->user_name
);
```

Or you could get it in the view without changing the controller and use this `$username->user_name`.

[Codeigniter - Generating Query Results](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: Awesome, I've got it to work. Thanks! I'll accept your answer in a few minutes.